# Docker: Unable login to Docker Hub from Windows

Tags: docker

I installed docker toolbox v17.03 in my windows 10. When I try to login using docker login, I get the following error.

error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-wincred": executable file not found in %PATH%, out: ``

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Really apologize for jumping too fast. I think I sorted out. I initially installed Docker for Windows to use Hyper-V for virtualization and then had to uninstall since Windows 10 Home is not supporting. Then I installed Docker Toolbox. Looks like this added wincred in config.json in the .docker dir. All started working after removed the entries in the config.json

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Worked for me as well. Don't forget to accept your own answer ;)

Comment: For the people who are not able to find docker directory, here it is `C:\Users\Administrator\.docker`

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to modify the config.json file. Just go to https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases and download the **docker-credential-wincred-v0.6.0-amd64.zip**. Unzip it and move the executable `docker-credential-wincred.exe` to the `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\` folder. It should do the trick.

Comment: In my case, unzipped it to C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin

Comment: In my case: c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\

Answer (score 1):

For me the following solved the issue. In

```
~/.docker/config.json
```

change **credsStore** to **credStore**

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with `Ubuntu 18-04` running on `WSL2` and found that using `docker` from a windows-console worked okay.